# Objective c - Letter & Points Model

Tags: objective-c, model, structure

I'm developing a word game and basically I want to assign an integer value to each character of the alphabet.

Currently, I have a helper to return the value for each char but I'm wondering how I should construct the initial data structure.

At the moment it is a dictionary containing each of the letters of the alphabet as the key and I want the points to be the object for that key. What is the best practise to set the points object?

I want to avoid things like this:

```
if      (_letter == 'a' || _letter == 'A') _points = 1;
else if (_letter == 'b' || _letter == 'B') _points = 4;
else if (_letter == 'c' || _letter == 'C') _points = 3;
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a 26-element C array of integers, where each integer is the point value of that letter, with the 0th element being A, the 1st element being B, etc. You then just lowercase the letter before subtracting `'a'` from it and use that as the index into the array. At this point, the only thing left is to prevent non-ASCII-alphabetic characters from being considered, which can be done with a simple range check after lowercasing (`if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')`).

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that chars *are* integers in C (and therefore Objective-C as well), and simply have an array of ints, keyed off the lowercase version of the char - 'a', like so:

```
int *letterValues[] = {1,4,3}; // a = 1, b=4, etc...
char thisChar = 'B';

int thisCharVal = letterValues[tolower(thisChar) - 'a'];
```

Note that this uses tolower, which is declared in  (std library), and that subtracting 'a' from a lowercase alpha char is essentially deducing it's "index" in the alphabet: 'a' - 'a' = 0, the "first" item, 'b'-'a' = 1, etc. Therefore, your array initializer (`{1,4,3}`), is simply the values you want to assign to the chars in order (or use designated initializers if you wish, and you *can* use chars there as well:

```
int *letterValues[] = {1,4,3, 'z'=4};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just teh standard latin alphabet, with no umlauts or other special characters, the easiest way is to just make an array of 26 ints for the "point" values:

```
int LookupPoints(char c)
{
    static const unsigned char Points[26]={1,4,3, ... };

    c=c|0x20;    /* all lower case */
    assert(c>='a' && c<='z');
    return Points[c-'a'];
}
```

If you want to include other characters you could check for them specifically, or make an alphabetically sorted array of structs (with the character and the value) to search with bsearch.

EDIT: of course, a dictionary will work too. Just use whatever feels like the easiest solution for your specific case.